# EventTrigger Not Working When Declared in Window.Resources in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, triggers, styles

I am new to WPF, so I may be missing something essential, but I have experimented and tried to come up with an explanation for the following phenomenon, to no avail.
Basically, the following code works (displays animation):

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="LoadStoryBoard"
AutoReverse="True"
RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button1" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Opacity)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.4" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Button x:Name="button1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource Load}">
<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LoadStoryBoard}" />
            </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

However, when I try to put the eventrigger in the Load Style in the following, the animation ceases to appear:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="LoadStoryBoard"
AutoReverse="True"
RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button1" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Opacity)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.4" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Style x:Key="Load" TargetType="Button">
...
<Style.Triggers>
    ...
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LoadStoryBoard}" />
            </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hey Clement, as @AnatoliyNikolaev says, all you need to do to make your 'broken' example work is to remove the `Storyboard.TargetName` property from the declaration of the `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Style` of triggers can not use objects with `TargetName`, such animation. To do this, they are placed in triggers template `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`. Quote from [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86f28ade-84ad-4470-bb17-f32402c34a6f/problem-using-sourcename-in-property-trigger-and-targetname-in-setter):

> TargetName is not intended for use within the Triggers collection of a Style. A style does not have a namescope, so it does not make sense to refer to elements by name there. But a template (either DataTemplate or ControlTemplate) does have a namescope.

The following works:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="LoadStoryBoard" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Opacity)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.4" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>       

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="button1" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />                                
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LoadStoryBoard}" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Name="TestButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Test" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Notice that now `TargetName` in the template specified in the `Border`:  `<Border x:Name="button1" .../>`.

*`Note:`* Or, you can just remove the `Storyboard.TargetName`, since it triggers the style is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have just tried placing my eventtrigger into controltemplate.triggers, but the animation does not work. I have also directly copied and pasted your code, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: @Clement Hoang: What exactly does not work? I can give the link to the project.

Comment: I can confirm that this code example worked just fine for me when I copied and pasted it into a new project.

Comment: Sorry, it works now. :)
On an unrelated note, suppose I want the storyboard to target another control when a certain trigger occurs, is eventtrigger the right way to go about doing so, or should I use something else?

Comment: @Clement Hoang: I think so. When you do an animation for specific control, such as `Button`, and this behavior is standard and *static* (for example: MouseOver, Loaded, etc), then it is better to use animation in `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` (such as my example). When animations are using an arbitrary number of controls in panel such as `Grid`, `StackPanel`, it is better to use  `EventTriggers` in (for example panel `Grid`) `<Grid.Triggers>`, pre-specifying the `TargetName`.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the `EventTrigger` is not working, but it is not because it was declared in the `Resources` section. To see this, you can move your style directly into the `Button` declaration where it still does not work:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LoadStoryBoard}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

However, if we move the declaration of the `Animation` from the `Resources` section, it works again:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Opacity)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.4" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

So it seems as though the problem has something to do with the `Storyboard` declared in the `Resources` section not being ready by the time the `Loaded` event fires. There is a similar problem noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919480/wpf-animation-doesnt-run-first-time).

However, just to confuse things more, if we then put the full declaration for the `Animation` into the `Style` declared in the `Resources` section, then now the `Style` works:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Load" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Opacity)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.4" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Button x:Name="button1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource Load}" />
```

I could speculate as to why this happens, but I'm guessing that there are very few WPF developers that really know why everything is the way that it is... I've learnt that if a particular declaration method works, use it and if not, try a different one.

**Background**

In WPF, there are four places where we can define `Triggers`; `Style.Triggers`, `ControlTemplate.Triggers`, `DataTemplate.Triggers` and `FrameworkElement.Triggers` (eg. `Button.Triggers`).

Basically, there is a huge flaw in the `FrameworkElement.Triggers` `TriggerCollection` in that it only accepts triggers of type `EventTrigger`. This can be seen on the [FrameworkElement.Triggers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers.aspx) page at MSDN where the following definition is given as to what this property can accept:

> One or more defined EventTrigger elements. Each such trigger is
>   expected to contain valid storyboard actions and references. Note that
>   this collection can only be established on the root element of a page.

The MSDN property pages for the other trigger properties each announce that they can accept either *Zero or more TriggerBase objects*, or *One or more TriggerBase objects*.

Furthermore, there are distinct rules that different triggers follow - a unified approach would have certainly helped newcomers to WPF. From the [FrameworkElement.Triggers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers.aspx) page:

> This property does not enable you to examine triggers that exist as
>   part of styles in use on this element. It only reports the collection
>   of triggers that are literally added to the collection, either in
>   markup or code. Elements do not typically have such elements existing
>   by default (through a template for instance); it is more common for
>   triggers that come from control compositing to be established in
>   styles instead.
>
> In terms of behavior (and trying to establish which effect came from
>   which element's declared Triggers collection), both the triggering
>   condition and the trigger effect might be on this element, or might be
>   on its child elements in the logical tree. Note that if you use
>   lifetime events such as Loaded to get this collection, the child
>   element's triggers might not yet be fully loaded, and the collection
>   will be smaller than it would truly be at run time.
>
> Note that the collection of triggers established on an element only
>   supports EventTrigger, not property triggers (Trigger). If you require
>   property triggers, you must place these within a style or template and
>   then assign that style or template to the element either directly
>   through the Style property, or indirectly through an implicit style
>   reference.

From the [DataTemplate.Triggers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.triggers.aspx) page at MSDN:

> If you are creating triggers within a data template, the setters of
>   the triggers should be setting properties that are within the scope of
>   the data template. Otherwise, it may be more suitable to create
>   triggers using a style that targets the type that contains the data.
>   For example, if you are binding a ListBox control, the containers are
>   ListBoxItem objects. If you are using triggers to set properties that
>   are not within the scope of the DataTemplate, then it may be more
>   suitable to create a ListBoxItem style and create triggers within that
>   style.

Unfortunately, all this extra information doesn't actually answer your question as to why the animation resource does not work in the `Style` resource, but hopefully now, you can see that the whole `Trigger` area is a bit of a complicated, messy area. Not being an expert myself, I just tend to use whichever method of declaring `Trigger`s that works.

I hope that helps in some way.

Comment: He is not working example because it points in the styles of `TargetName`, but it was not supported. If he removes it, he will have to work in the two cases.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev, he has a working example already... he's asking why the other example doesn't work, not for a working example.

Comment: So that's it, if in not working example, it will remove the `Storyboard.TargetName="button1"` the example what will work.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now... wow! How did I not notice that?!!? +1 for you my friend!